# How to replace response body in WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0 Custom Handler

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have written a CustomHandler which verifies if there is a specific key in the request. If the key is missing, handler should send back response to the client with the text saying that the key is missing. When a get request is sent to the server without key in the header, server responds back to the client with the modified payload. But, when a post request is sent to server, it sends back the original payload sent by the client. Below is the code that sends back response to the client with modified payload.

```
private void handleAuthenticationFailure(MessageContext messageContext, APISecurityException e){                

    SOAPBody body = messageContext.getEnvelope().getBody();

    for (Iterator itr = body.getChildElements(); itr.hasNext();) {
        OMElement child = (OMElement) itr.next();
        child.detach();
    }

    org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MC = ((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).
            getAxis2MessageContext();

    axis2MC.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/xml");        
    axis2MC.removeProperty("NO_ENTITY_BODY");
    axis2MC.setProperty("HTTP_SC", HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

    messageContext.setResponse(true);
    messageContext.setProperty("RESPONSE", "true");
    messageContext.setTo(null);       

    messageContext.getEnvelope().getBody().addChild(getFaultPayload(e));

    Axis2Sender.sendBack(messageContext);        
}

private OMElement getFaultPayload(APISecurityException e) {
    OMFactory fac = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
    OMNamespace ns = fac.createOMNamespace(APISecurityConstants.API_SECURITY_NS,
            APISecurityConstants.API_SECURITY_NS_PREFIX);
    OMElement payload = fac.createOMElement("fault", ns);

    OMElement errorCode = fac.createOMElement("code", ns);
    errorCode.setText(String.valueOf(e.getErrorCode()));
    OMElement errorMessage = fac.createOMElement("message", ns);
    errorMessage.setText("Missing Credentials");
    OMElement errorDetail = fac.createOMElement("description", ns);
    errorDetail.setText(e.getMessage());

    payload.addChild(errorCode);
    payload.addChild(errorMessage);
    payload.addChild(errorDetail);
    return payload;
}
```

Am I missing something ? How do I drop the original payload of the post request and send back the modified payload ? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement: replacing an arbitrary string within the body payload of an HTTP response. We achieved this through custom mediation, but the approach should be equally valid through a handler.

We avoided using XML parsing, construction, and injection by using synapse JsonUtil (org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil), specifically `String jsonResponse = JsonUtil.jsonPayloadToString(axis2)` to read the payload body and `JsonUtil.newJsonPayload(axis2, jsonResponse, true, true)` to write.

If you require the payload to be in XML, you'll want to look at `Utils.setFaultPayload` and `Utils.sendFault`, which can be found in their org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers package at https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/Utils.java.

```
    public static void setFaultPayload(MessageContext messageContext, OMElement payload) {
    org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MC = ((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).
            getAxis2MessageContext();
    JsonUtil.removeJsonPayload(axis2MC);
    messageContext.getEnvelope().getBody().addChild(payload);
    Map headers = (Map) axis2MC.getProperty(org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext.TRANSPORT_HEADERS);
    String acceptType = (String) headers.get(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT);
    //If an Accept header has been provided.
    if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(acceptType) && !"*/*".equals(acceptType)){
        axis2MC.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.MESSAGE_TYPE, acceptType);
    }
}

    public static void sendFault(MessageContext messageContext, int status) {
    org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MC = ((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).
            getAxis2MessageContext();

    axis2MC.setProperty(NhttpConstants.HTTP_SC, status);
    messageContext.setResponse(true);
    messageContext.setProperty("RESPONSE", "true");
    messageContext.setTo(null);        
    axis2MC.removeProperty("NO_ENTITY_BODY");

    // Always remove the ContentType - Let the formatter do its thing
    axis2MC.removeProperty(Constants.Configuration.CONTENT_TYPE);
    Map headers = (Map) axis2MC.getProperty(org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext.TRANSPORT_HEADERS);
    if (headers != null) {
        headers.remove(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        headers.remove(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        headers.remove(HttpHeaders.HOST);
    }
    Axis2Sender.sendBack(messageContext);
}
```